# Annoying differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I feel like this should be really easy, but how do I solve $$f'(x+1)=f(x)?$$ I am extremely new to differential equations, and can't figure out what I'm missing. Most resources that I look at are in terms of $$y''+y'=e^x$$ or whatever, and none that I've seen discuss composition of functions. WolframAlpha can't figure out what I'm telling it; it doesn't seem to think that there's anything to solve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a [delay defferential equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation). For that particular equation, you can fix the value of the solution on any interval of length $1$, say $f(x)=\phi(x)$ for $x\in[-1,0]$, and then construct the solution on $[0,1]$ as follows:
$$
f'(x)=f(x-1)=\phi(x-1)\text{ if }0\le x\le1\implies f(x)=\phi(0)+\int_0^x\phi(t-1)\,dt,\quad 0\le x\le1.
$$
Now you can find $f$ on $[1,2]$ and so on.